# how to create automated batch job with fixed width file format

Tags: apex, batch

My object name is `Account` and it has fields(length):

- `Name (10)`
- `Account Number (8)`
- `Email (15)`
- `Phone (10)`

The query should fetch the data from the above object and download it as a fixed width text file display according to the field length in a standard text file.

```
Name       Account Number   Email         Phone
Test1       12345678      test@test.com   12345678
Test2       87654321      test@test.com   12345678
```

The text file should display the records in the above format. Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I've had to export a fixed width file before from Salesforce, and it wasn't elegant but it did work.

I created an object to store lines of the file (with an index so I could sort by that in a query) since it could get pretty huge but if you can fit it all in a long text field then use one of those. Simply generate the data in the batch, adding the appropriate number of spaces between fields etc. to get the format how you want it.

For instance, if the name is up to 20 characters in the format then you'd do something like this:

```
String outLine += name.rightPad(20).left(20);
```

Then you could either email the file out of Salesforce, fire it off to a webservice, or do what I did for this particular client and setup a cron job on a local machine that would use dataloader to pull the information from Salesforce and do some file manipulation via a batch file (for various client-specific reasons this had to be on a Windows box).

Once the data has been pulled out you should update the record(s) in Salesforce so that they're not pulled again.